# Bundler: list gems in a group

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

For example, I have the following Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :example_group do
  gem 'example_gem'
  gem 'another_example_gem'
end
```

How can I list all gems inside :example_group in Ruby? Not really looking for a shell command.

Comment: "Not really looking for a shell command." - What are you looking for then?

Answer (score 1):

Adapting from the [Bundler::Graph](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/f9a3a5148e7902ae4e30e837060806067e9025f5/lib/bundler/graph.rb), you could have :

```
Bundler.load.current_dependencies.select{|dep|
  dep.groups.include?(:example_group)}.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but some ideas:

- Gemfile is ruby code, meaning you can write plain ruby there
- the 'gem' method in Gemfile does return the current list of [dependencies](http://rubydoc.info/github/carlhuda/bundler/master/Bundler/Dependency)

So something like:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gems = []

group :example_group do
  gem 'example_gem'
  gems << gem 'another_example_gem'
end

group_gems = gems.select { |gm| gm.groups.include?(:example_group) }.map { |gm| gm.name }
p group_gems.uniq
```

Will print out your gems in the group when you use bundler (bundle install for example). Instead of printing them, you could save them somewhere.